# VMware Player ver. 6 & 7 failing to work on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, vmware, vmware-player

After upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04, my VMware player stopped working.

I suspect that installing the latest VMware Player software will fix this problem. I believe this because I checked the compatibility of VMware software for 16.04 and there are compatible versions. The page which shows compatibility: http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software&testConfig=16

However, I do not want to upgrade to the latest VMware software because I move my virtual machines from one physical machine to another, and I strongly believe that once I run a VM in the latest VMware player, the same VM will no longer work on other machines with an older version of VMware.

Any advice on how to make VMware Player version 6 or 7 work on 16.04?

**Error:**

I dumped the error log (/tmp/vmware-root/vmware-modconfig-23470.log) here: https://pastebin.com/4NmkPzYD

the visual error is below:

[image]

I have also tried to tackle this problem on my own by installing & reinstalling VMware and running very many terminal commands, but at this point I am way out of my league and do not want to do something I will later regret (it's been done too many times....).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What causes you the think that a newer version of VMWare will cause your VM to become inoperable?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I believe that once I run a VM in a newer version of VMware player, the VM will be modified and will not work on older versions of VMware player. This is indeed an assumption. I will test to see if my assumption is wrong next week.